# How to highlight selected tab in Web Forms including Master Page

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

I know without a master page it is as simple as setting the tab for each page to selected but how do I do this with master page?

**Home Page**

[image]

**Houses Page (The home tab stays selected even though its on the houses page)**

[image]

**Expected Output**

[image]

I used the following tutorial [Highlighting the selected jquery tab using asp.net Master page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085911/highlighting-the-selected-jquery-tab-using-asp-net-master-page)

**Master Page**

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#scrollToTop').bind("click", function () {
                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1200);
                return false;
            });

            function setCurrentTab(selectedTab) {
                $('li').removeClass('selected');
                $('[id=selectedTab]').addClass('selected');
            }
        });
    </script>

<div id="navigation">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="tab1">
                            <a href="Home.aspx">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="tab2">
                            <a href="Houses.aspx">Houses</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="tab3">
                            <a href="About.aspx">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="tab4">
                            <a href="Contact.aspx">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

**Houses.aspx**

```
<script>
        setCurrentTab('tab2');
    </script>
```

**CSS**

```
#navigation li, #navigation li a:hover, #navigation li.selected a {
    background-image: url(../images/bg-menu.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this code

```
$('[id=selectedTab]').addClass('selected');
```

with

```
$('[id='+selectedTab+']').addClass('selected');
```

or with

```
$('#'+selectedTab).addClass('selected');
```

You have your selected tab id in selectedTab variable, but you are using it as literal, so concat this selectedTab with id.

On Houses.aspx, call setCurrentTab function on document.ready. like

```
$(function(){ setCurrentTab('tab2'); });
```

Comment: I replaced that line with both changes its still the same does the setCurrentTab(tab2'); need to be inside a function on the houses page? or is my setCurrentTab function positioned correctly?

Comment: In houses.aspx, where you have placed that setCurrentTab calling.

Comment: You should also enclose your `setCurrentTab('tab2');` in  `$(function () {...});`.

Comment: its placed just under the content place holder inside script tags

Comment: I placed setCurrentTab('tab2'); inside $(function () {...}; its still not selecting

Comment: Ok, on your master page, move definition of setCurrentTab, out side of $(function(){..});